# Making an Image a "boundary"

Tags: java, collision, boundary

I am working on a game in which you are a simple circle that fires bullets and its multiplayer and so on. Well, I am trying to make boundaries sort of like a maze type thing that u have to go through I have tried collision detection like this:

```
public void checkCollisions(){
    Rectangle r1 = bo.getBounds();
    Rectangle d = p.getBounds();
    if (d.intersects(r1))
        border = true;
}
```

And basically if border = true then i stop the character from moving. I have 2 problems when i do this,

1. He doesnt stop just goes REALLY slow.
2. He stays at the REALLY slow state even off the border.

I use border like this:

```
boolean border = false;
```

then in my paint method i state this:

```
if (border)
        p.dx = 0;
        p.dy = 0;
```

p represents the Guy class :P
More of the dx and dy:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int key = e.getKeyCode();

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    dx = -2;

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    dx = 2;

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    dy = -2;

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    dy = 2;
```

and for keyReleased i just change the value of dx and dy to 0
also for how the guy moves:

```
public void move() {
x = x + dx;
y = y + dy;
}
```

Please help me figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you show where you use `border`?

Comment: i just made an edit to it. Its just a boolean and if it is false then nothing happens but when it is true i stop the guy from moving

Comment: You need to show more. And shouldn't checkCollisions take parameters and return a boolean?

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your code.. basically how you have used p.dx and p.dy to change the guy's coordinates on the screen >

Comment: You realize `p.dy = 0` is not in the if-block, right?  It will always occur.  I posted an answer thinking it would never zero out, but I had it wrong: the y-speed will **always** zero out.

Comment: One thing to note (I can only keep commenting since you've given so little context) is that it's very bad to have `paint` contain actual game logic.  Paint should not change your state, or "model"...it should only ever be responsible for *reading* that state to render it to the screen.  Move that logic to a "recalculate" portion of your game loop.

Comment: Ok ill give that a try haha thank you so much. Im just starting off in java (as u could tell) and this is my first game. I was following a tutorial and i guess i did something wrong. Thank you. And i will move the if statement to another class :D

Comment: @Michael: Good luck!  If you continue to need help try to get your code down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  It's a bit of a guessing game if we can't see (at least mostly) sufficient code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Alright I have added more and notice it is a bit crazy i will try to get it down to an SSCCE. Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and java alike

Answer (score 1):

OK, I still think a full restructuring of your game logic is in order, but I think I can shed light as to what's going on.  Let's look at the various places where things are happening:

1. PAINT: On the Swing thread, when `paint()` is called, you see if there were collisions and if so zero out the speeds (assuming you fix that if block).
2. KEY: On the Swing thread, when a key is pressed, you set the speed according to the key pressed.
3. CHECK: At some unknown point, you check for collisions and record whether there was one.
4. MOVE: At some unknown point, you update your "guy's" position with the speed.

So here's the problem: in Java, just like any other program, you get multiple key pressed events when you're holding down a key.  There will be a short delay between the first and second, and then they will repeat rapidly.  Try it in a text box in your browser, the same behaviour occurs there.

So how does that affect you?  Well, you're probably getting into a scenario like this:

```
PAINT -> speed set to zero
KEY -> speed set back to -2
MOVE -> guy is moved -2
CHECK -> border = false
PAINT -> speed set to zero again
```

Really, if you restructure the code so that you get a game loop that looks something like this:

```
public void runGame() {
    while(true) {
        updateSpeeds();
        updatePositionFromSpeed();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Where `updateSpeeds()` would instead query whether the key is down or up and also compute whether the guy could move in that direction, and `updatePositionFromSpeed()` would update the guy's position.  Then `paint()` would rely **only** on the guy's `x` and `y` coordinates, would not write to them, and would not need to know about the speed.

Comment: @Michael: if Mark's answer helped you then please up-vote his answer. If it solved your question or is the best answer in a reasonable amount of time (say a day or two), then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's a very easy solution.

Here's a bit of my pseudo code.

```
        if(player.getBounds().intersects(wall.getBounds())){
            //Go Back to prior position, regardless of direction coming from. Since the reverse velocity X and velocity Y directions are taken care off
            x -= velX;
            y -= velY;

            //Then Stop at that prior position to make next move
            velX = 0;
            velY = 0;
        }
```